# create Directory in Onedrive using android

Tags: android, onedrive, live-sdk

Hi I am using Microsoft liveSDK for android in may application. I am using follwing method for folder creation.

LiveOperation postAsync(String path, JSONObject body, LiveOperationListener listener)

I need to create directory(folder structure) in Onedrive .I have absoute path(eg: A/B/C).If A/B is already exist, I want to create folder C inside folder B(dont want to Overwirte). Have any method is available for this purpose

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LiveSDK does not support creating a folders path hierarchy.  You'd need to create a folder, get its id, and then create the tree of sub-folders under that path.

There is a OneDrive API that does support this functionality, https://dev.onedrive.com/, which allows for both path based lookup, and path hierarchy creation.

To [create a folder](https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm) craft a request like the following, in this example we will create the folder hierarchy **a > b > c > d > e** in a single request.

```
POST https://api.onedrive.com/v1.0/drive/root:/a/b/c/d:/children
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name":"e",
    "folder":{}
}
```

Comment: Note: there is no SDK OneDrive API for Android at the time of this posting, if you are looking for examples as to make a request like the example, see the sample project https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-explorer-android